# C# Threads error el proceso no puede tener acceso al archvo porque esa siendo utilizado en otro proceso

Tags: c#, hilos

Estoy trabajando en C# con hilos pero no me permite imprimirlos en un txt dado que ocurre el error:

> El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo
>   'C:\Users\wuesi\Desktop\Datos.txt' porque está siendo utilizado en
>   otro proceso. System.IO.IOException

```
namespace threads
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            productor hilo_Obj1 = new productor(); 
            productor hilo_Obj2 = new productor();
            productor hilo_Obj3 = new productor();

            Consumidor hilo_obj4 = new Consumidor(); 
            Receprto hilo_obj5 = new Receprto();

            Thread hilo_Uno = new Thread(new ThreadStart(hilo_Obj1.run)); 
            Thread hilo_Dos = new Thread(new ThreadStart(hilo_Obj2.run));
            Thread hilo_Tres = new Thread(new ThreadStart(hilo_Obj3.run));
            Thread hilo_Cuatro = new Thread(new ThreadStart(hilo_obj4.run_C));
            Thread hilo_Cinco = new Thread(new ThreadStart(hilo_obj5.Run_R)); 

            hilo_Uno.Start();  
            hilo_Dos.Start();   
            hilo_Tres.Start();
            hilo_Cuatro.Start();   
            hilo_Cinco.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    class productor : Consumidor
    {
        int M,i;
        public double dataqueue_a, dataqueue_i, dataqueue_c;

        public productor()
        {
            M = 5;
            i = 0;
            dataqueue_a = 0;
            dataqueue_c = 0;
            dataqueue_i = 0;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            do
            {
                Random aleatorio_C = new Random();//genero datos entre 97 y 122 para despues imprimirlos con el valor de ascii y generar datos char
                int a;
                for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
                {

                    a = aleatorio_C.Next(97, 122);
                    dataqueue_a = a;

                    if (dataqueue_a != 0)
                    {
                        dataqueue.Enqueue(dataqueue_a);

                    }
                }

                Random aleatorio_I = new Random();
                int b;
                for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
                {

                    b = aleatorio_I.Next(1, 50);
                    dataqueue_i = b;
                    if (dataqueue_i != 0)
                    {
                        dataqueue.Enqueue(dataqueue_i);
                    }
                }

                Random aleatorio_F = new Random();
                double c;
                for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
                {

                    c = aleatorio_F.NextDouble();
                    dataqueue_c = c;
                    if (dataqueue_c != 0)
                    {
                        dataqueue.Enqueue(dataqueue_c);
                    }
                }
            } while (dataqueue.Count == 45);

                semaforo = "Done";
                run_C();


        }        
 }



    class Consumidor:Receprto
    {
        public String semaforo;
        public Queue dataqueue = new Queue();

        public void run_C()
        {            
                while (dataqueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (sem == true)
                    {
                        sem = false;
                        str = (double)dataqueue.Dequeue();
                        Run_R();
                          sem = true;
                      }
                }

        }
    }
}

class Receprto
{
    public double str;
    public bool sem=true;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\wuesi\\Desktop\\Datos.txt");

    public async void Run_R()
    {
        if (str != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            sw.Write(str);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que el error es bastante claro, intentas usar el archivo de forma asíncrona y no tomas en cuenta que dos procesos pueden intentar acceder al mismo recurso al mismo tiempo (race condition: https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condición_de_carrera). Una solución es usar lock.

Comment: Que es lock????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes una condicion de carrera. Cuando inicalizas los hilos, solo uno a la vez puede abrir el `StreamWriter` y escribir en el archivo, de lo contrario te lanza un error donde hay otro proceso que esta utilizando el archivo.

Intenta utilizando un `lock`. En esencia, un `lock` bloquea el acceso a cierto algoritmo si detecta que otro proceso esta accediendo al objeto *'lockeado'*:

```
class Receprto
{
    public double str;
    public bool sem=true;


    // objeto que servira como indicador si esta siendo accedido por otro hilo
    private static object _lockObject = new object();
    public async void Run_R()
    {
           lock(_lockObject)
           {
              StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\wuesi\\Desktop\\Datos.txt");
              // este codigo se ejecutara siempre y cuando
              // el objecto _lockObject este marcado como libre por el lock

              if (str != null)
              {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                sw.Write(str);
              }
              sw.Close();
           }
    }
}
```

Lo que hace es que bloquea la entrada a la inicializacion del `StreamWriter` si otro hilo esta accediendo al bloque `lock` y cuando termine, entonces el hilo en espera entra al `lock`.